# In pipelined processor design, why register file read/write are performed in half cycle?

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

I'm reading about pipelined MIPS processor design in the book "Digital Design and Computer Architecture (Second Edition)" by David Money Harris and Sarah L. Harris.

In section 7.5.3 "Hazards" it says (page 415):

> The register file can be read and written in the same cycle. The write takes place during the first half of the cycle and the read takes place during the second half of the cycle, so a register can be written and read back in the same cycle without introducing a hazard.

**My question is: why can't the register file just get read and written simultaneously?**

Actually, my question is quite similar to [this stackexchange one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109430/in-instructions-pipelining-why-does-register-read-write-take-up-only-half-clock), but the answers there does not make me fully clear. Also I'm not allowed to comment there due to lack of reputation, so I start this question.

I think for a SRAM register file with 2 read ports and 1 write port, as shown [in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Regfile_cell.png), it seems perfectly legal to read and write the same address simultaneously. Although the write operation will cause the bits stored in cross-coupled inverters unstable for a while, as along as the clock cycle of the pipelined processor is long enough, the bits will get stabilized. Therefore the read operation, which is fully combinational, can get the correct data. Then why not read and write simultaneously?

**My second question is, if we must use such a register file as suggested by the book, which read in the first half cycle, and write in the second half cycle, how to implement this register file as circuits?**

My naive solution is to redefine `write_enable` and `read_enable` signal of the register file. Let `write_enable = write_enable & clock` and `read_enable = read_enable & ~clock`. But the book seems to suggest to write on the failing edge, see HDL example 7.6 register file code comment (page 435):

> for pipelined processor, write third port on falling edge of clk

I would assume a clock cycle starts with 1 in the first half, then drops to 0 in the second half. Therefore I feel writing on the falling edge actually results in writing in the second half of the clock cycle, not the first half. What's more, it does nothing to ensure reading in the second half of the cycle. How can it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the answer you linked, a 2 read, 1 write requirement can be accomplished with only two ports -- one bidirectional and one read, with reduced circuitry and accompanying other benefits.  Your thought is to simply use fully 3 ports for this, and yes, that should work, of course without those benefits.

Comment: This sounds more like a circuit-design question that might get a better answer on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/, especially re: downsides of instability from cross-coupled inverters and so on.  Could be a very expensive power spike, IDK.

Comment: Re: part 2: Are you sure the falling edge is the second half of the clock cycle?  If the whole pipeline is designed to latch data between stages on the falling edge, starting the write then is the first half of the clock.  (I don't have the book so IDK if that's the explanation).